# Question on vulnerable time of pure aloha, and why it does include propagation time

Tags: computer-networks

I have read that pure Aloha's vulnerable time is 2*transmission time. But shouldn't it also include propagation time? What if a frame is propagating in media and gets collided with another frame (transmission of frame is completed)?